# Can System Settings be made unique to a Power Plan?

Tags: windows-10, power-management, windows-10-v1607

I have a few Power Plans that I use for my laptop, but the two I *thought* were most useful were my two High Performance plans: one was supposed to sleep the machine when the lid was closed, and the other was supposed to keep the machine running when the lid is closed.

I found that this isn't the case, and that *System Settings* in Power Options actually apply to *all* Power Plans:

[image]

Excerpt:

> The changes that you make to the settings on this page apply to all of your power plans.

Is it possible for these settings to be customized to each Power Plan, without any registry tweaks? I tried searching for a solution however didn't find any relivant results.

Comment: No; If both Power Plans are battery plans then what happens on Battery will happen to both

Comment: @Ramhound This has nothing to do with battery, in fact these settings are available on desktops with the same problem.

Comment: Well the same goes for the behavior defined by "plugged in", and even on a desktop, the power button will only have one behavior.  *I would hope that desktops don't have a way to define what behavior happens while "on battery"

Comment: @Ramhound I see where you're coming from now, kinda annoying though. Might have to write a small service that switches the two depending on the power plan.